# Array keeps getting replaced when being added to a dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, for-loop

Im trying to make a JSON object, which is basically a dictionary. This is my code which created a dictionary:

```
# Adding the data to the JSONData object
JSONData[str(gerechtNaam)] = { 
    "afbeeldingURL": gerechtAfbeelding,
    "receptURL": recept,
    "prijs": totalePrijs,
    "porties": porties,
    "moeilijkheid" :moeilijkheid,
    "caloriePortie": calorien,
    "voorbereidingsTijd": voorbereidingsTijd,
    "wachtTijd": wachtTijd,
    "totaleTijd": totaleTijd,
    "ingredienten": naamEnKwantiteitIngredienten
}
```

This works, and generates the following:

```
{
    'Gerooktekipsalade met avocado en walnoten': { 
        'afbeeldingURL': 'https://static-images.jumbo.com/product_images/Recipe_502535-01_560x560.jpg',
        'receptURL': 'http://www.jumbo.com/gerooktekipsalade-met-avocado-en-walnoten/502535/',
        'prijs': 16.868000000000002,
        'porties': '4 porties',
        'moeilijkheid': 'Eenvoudig',
        'caloriePortie': '842 kcal per persoon',
        'voorbereidingsTijd': '15 min',
        'wachtTijd': '0',
        'totaleTijd': '15 min',
        'ingredienten': [
            '2 kroppen minisla romaine ',
            '200 g cherrytomaatjes',
            '4 stengels bleekselderij',
            '2 friszoete handappels ',
            '380 g Nieuwe Standaard Kip gerookte kipfilet ',
            '2 bosuitjes',
            '2 avocado',
            '150 ml whisky-cocktailsaus',
            '3 el bieslook',
            '60 g walnoten',
            '1 stokbrood',
            '1 snufje peper'
        ]
    }
}
```

Which I then convert using the following code:

`with open('receptData.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(JSONData, outfile)`

This works, and generated working JSON. The only problem is that when trying to run the code twice in a for loop, the last variabel, called 'ingredienten' which is a list that gets created in the loop, gets replaced for all objects in the dictionary. So when the second 'ingredienten' array is created, the 'ingredienten' array that had already been made and added to JSONData gets replaced by the new one. All the other variables stay correct, yet the list/array gets replaced every time the loop runs.

So the second time the code runs, this is the dictionary I get:

```
{
    'Gerooktekipsalade met avocado en walnoten': {
        'afbeeldingURL': 'https://static-images.jumbo.com/product_images/Recipe_502535-01_560x560.jpg',
        'receptURL': 'http://www.jumbo.com/gerooktekipsalade-met-avocado-en-walnoten/502535/',
        'prijs': 16.868000000000002,
        'porties': '4 porties',
        'moeilijkheid': 'Eenvoudig',
        'caloriePortie': '842 kcal per persoon',
        'voorbereidingsTijd': '15 min',
        'wachtTijd': '0',
        'totaleTijd': '15 min',
        'ingredienten': **[
            '4 avocado',
            '100 g gerookte zalm',
            '8 kleine eieren ',
            '25 g alfalfa',
            '1 snufje peper',
            '1 bakplaat'
        ]**
    },
    'Gevulde avocado met ei en zalm uit de oven': {
        'afbeeldingURL': 'https://static-images.jumbo.com/product_images/Recipe_502536-01_560x560.jpg',
        'receptURL': 'http://www.jumbo.com/gevulde-avocado-met-ei-en-zalm-uit-de-oven/502536/',
        'prijs': 8.72,
        'porties': '4 porties',
        'moeilijkheid': 'Eenvoudig',
        'caloriePortie': '234 kcal per persoon',
        'voorbereidingsTijd': '10 min',
        'wachtTijd': '15 min',
        'totaleTijd': '25 min',
        'ingredienten': **[
            '4 avocado',
            '100 g gerookte zalm',
            '8 kleine eieren ',
            '25 g alfalfa',
            '1 snufje peper',
            '1 bakplaat'
        ]**
    }
}
```

In which the first 'ingredienten' list is now the same as the second one, which should not be the case. I've tried multiple things but none worked....

Comment: can you post the code that generates `'ingredienten'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you haven't shown the code that creates it, I'm pretty sure the problem is that you're reusing the variable `naamEnKwantiteitIngredienten`, which is the list you're using as the value pointed to by the `'ingredienten'` key in your dictionary. If that list gets modified in place (perhaps by filling it up with a different set of ingredients), you'll also see the modified version in your previous dictionary if you haven't dumped it to a JSON string yet.

There are I think a two main ways you could fix the problem.

One is to create the JSON immediately after you make the dictionary, rather than waiting to do it later. While this might resolve this issue, it might be inconvenient for your program (or impossible, if you need all the dictionaries to be defined at the same time for other reasons).

The other solution is to make sure that the dictionaries you create are independent of each other. Rather than reusing the same list in all of them, you should make sure that each one contains a separate list. The most obvious place to fix this may be wherever you create the value that ends up in `naamEnKwantiteitIngredienten`, but you could instead fix it within the code you show by copying the list just before you put it in the dictionary:

```
JSONData[str(gerechtNaam)] = { 
    "afbeeldingURL": gerechtAfbeelding,
    "receptURL": recept,
    "prijs": totalePrijs,
    "porties": porties,
    "moeilijkheid" :moeilijkheid,
    "caloriePortie": calorien,
    "voorbereidingsTijd": voorbereidingsTijd,
    "wachtTijd": wachtTijd,
    "totaleTijd": totaleTijd,
    "ingredienten": naamEnKwantiteitIngredienten[:]     # slice here to copy the list!
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you! The second solution fixed the problem instantly!